# How to get the position of a gameobject every frame?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I basically want to make a gameobject turn around after it reaches a certain position in space. I have a prefab, create the gameobject and make it move randomly. However, printing the position value gives me the same value (0,4,0) which is basically the spawners location. I want the location of the object while its moving through space. Here is the code:

```
If (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
  direction = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1.0f,1.0f), Random.Range(-1.0f,1.0f),     Random.Range(-1.0f,1.0f)); 
 GameObject sphere = Instantiate(spherePrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
 sphere.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = direction * speed; // this moves the object randomly
 position = sphere.transform.position;
 Debug.Log(position); // This prints the spawners location every frame but no the spheres.
```

I have only created a spawner object in the scene and just instantiate the spheres with my script.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not updating the value you're printing in your log.

The position variable only holds the world position of the prefab at the moment it is instantiated.

Here is a basic script based on your code which gives the world position as you would expect it.

Below, spherePrefab is a 3D game object sphere on which I've only added a Rigidbody with default parameters.

Use case is as follows : Press the mouse button down, then watch the Unity console.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject spherePrefab;

    const float SPEED = 2f;

    // Initialization
    Vector3 _sphere_position = Vector3.zero;
    bool _display_log = false;
    GameObject _sphere_ref = null;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector3 direction = new(Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f));

            _sphere_ref = Instantiate(spherePrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            _sphere_ref.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = direction * SPEED; // this moves the object randomly
            _sphere_position = _sphere_ref.transform.position;

            Debug.Log(_sphere_position); // This prints the spawners location every frame but no the spheres.

            _display_log = true;
        }

        // This case is expected to be entered after setting sphere_ref in order not to be null
        if (_display_log)
        {
            // Update the value
            _sphere_position = _sphere_ref.transform.position;

            // Print it
            Debug.Log(_sphere_position);
        }
    }
}
```